# Global error handling issue

Tags: angular, error-handling, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have configured my global error handler:

```
[{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler}]
```

so basically if error happens I am calling my service that dispatching the action so then I am displaying the material snackbar with an error message:

```
export class AppService {

  constructor(store: Store<fromRoot.State>) { }

  public push(message: string, action?: string, config?: MdSnackBarConfig) {
    const alert: AppAlert = { message: message, action: action, config: config };
    this.store.dispatch(new appAlert.DisplayAppAlertAction(alert));
  }
}
```

The thing is that whatever I am dispatching in my `handleError()` the store just not getting updated.

```
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  /** */
  handleError(error: any): void {
     this.appAlertService.push('Error here', 'OK', config); // not firing the reducer
  }
}
```

All my dispatchers are working fine outside the `handleError()` but with this one as I checked in debug the `reducers` just not getting called.

Basically in case of error `handleError()` getting called then `dispatcher` getting fired but state is not getting mutatated and the reason why is because reducer is not getting called in that case. But all good if I am calling the same service (`AppService`) form any component, or anywhere else outside `handleError()`.

Also what I just bright the whole `Store` in to my `GlobalErrorHandler` instead of using my `AppService` just to see if it makes any difference but turned out getting the same result just by `dispatching` the action directly form `handleError()` - `reducer` still not getting called.

Any ideas why?

UPDATE

My service is actually getting called by effect, basically as being suggested @olsn I added `.catch` to that as well:

```
 @Effect()
    search$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(stuff.LOAD)
        .mergeMap(() =>
          this.myService.getStuff()
            .map((stuff: Stuff[]) =>
              new stuff.LoadSuccessAction(stuff)
            )
            .catch((): any => {
              throw new HttpError();
          })
        ).catch((): any => {
              throw new HttpError();
          });
```

But didn't help Both of the `.catch()` blocks getting called at first when error thrown. But then when clicking on any `buttons/routes` to get to`handleError()` still my dispatch is not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? At what point in detail is the call-chain not continued? Is the `this.store.dispatch` called? Is the `handleError` even called? Have you tried using breakpoints yet, inspecting the variables ect.?

Comment: @olsn I did debug the app, all good except `reducer` not getting called from within the `handleError()` function, as I mention that in the last sentence, sorry if it wasn't so clear. Just added the missed piece of details.

Comment: How and when is your handleError-method called? Does it happen to be during an effect or as a direct result of another store dispatch?

Comment: @olsn So basically I am throwing the custom error from my service by `http.get("wrong-url").catch((): any => { throw new HttpError(); });` so then in order the `handleError()` get called I need just to click on some button/route. Then I get in to `handleError()`

Comment: Does the click involve any store.dispatch()? Why i'm asking is because you cannot have a store.dispatch inside another one or inside an effect - this will cause issues and malfunctions - as a quick test (not as a final fix) you could wrap your dispatch in the handleError in an setTimeout and see if that works.

Comment: @olsn ahhh btw, I have an effect that actually called the service that throwing error I am talking about (before `handleError()` is called), wrapping in to `setTimeout()` now.

Comment: Try handling the error in the effect - otherwise it probably breaks the effect - the .catch(..) won't prevent that since it's just throwing another error

Comment: @olsn so should I just take out the `catch` from my `http.get()` and put it in to effect? Of should I keep it + add additional `.catch` to `effect`?

Comment: You can keep it there if you want - just ensure that the effect will catch any errors because in rxjs observables that throw an error will be unsubscribed and finalized and not be usable any more (i'm not sure if ngrx does anything to handle that but i suspect it is not)

Comment: @olsn just tried to wrap my dispatch in to `setTimeout` - didn't, help, also added the `.catch` to `effect` but dispatch that is inside `hendleError()` still not getting called. Also just updated the question with these details.

Comment: __Don't__ throw another error inside a `.catch` - or the catch will have absolutely no benefit ;-) - just handle the error directly in the catch block, and return an action instead - so instead of the `throw` you do: `return Observable.of(new MyCustomHttpAction(someDetails))` - and then have some service(or effect) listen to the `MyCustomHttpAction` to handle it accordingly.

Comment: @olsn why would you handle the error like in a `.catch` block if it is getting handler by `handleError()`? Yeah there is an issue that `handleError()` is not firing after error happend but only if after I click a button...so should I just call the `handleError()` manually then?

Comment: ....because if you throw an error inside a stream, the stream will be "dead", i will not work any more, in other words, it will break your `effect` - if you read the documentation there should be plenty of examples on many best-practices related to ngrx/rxjs - and if you want to use effects, then you should stick to using them how they are meant to be used: they listen to an (or many) action and return an (or many) action - simple as that - no error throwing, that's just how rxjs and therefor ngrx is designed - it's a little different yes, but please read the docs